# Cannot export content of ultrawebgrid to excel spreadsheet from WebDialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, infragistics

I'm using window.showModalDialog to open a modal window using Javascript. I have to include this line in the `< HEAD >` html of the modal window: `<base target=_self>` because whenever that page posted back, it would spawn off a new window!!

In this Modal Window I need to have a File Download functionality. The problem is that using  the File Download dialog don't popup, but if I remove the  the File Download dialog appears but then again, another window shows off. Is there by any chance that I can disable `<base target_self>` while I am downloading the content of my grid? By the way, I am using Infragistics UltraWebGridExcelExporter for this.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Since you're using Infragistics, have you considered using ther WebDialog (http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet/dialog-window/) instead of ModalDialog? It should help avoid many issues and it does have "modal" feature.

Comment: Hello Yuriy, unfortunately, the webdialog of infragistics is currently not available to the version that we are using.

Comment: It seems to be a well known problem, try Googling it or search SO, for example this is one of possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12858575/961695

Comment: @GianIsTheName Where is the grid and exporter?  Are they both on the dialog or are they on the page that shows the dialog?  Is the implementation like the link that Yuriy provided?

Comment: Hi alhalama, the grid and the exporter are both on the web dialog. The implementation is different though.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned this is a well known problem. One possible solution (I haven't got a chance to try it, but it seems logical) for the button that initiates download **onClientClick** try adding following JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].setAttibute("target","")
```

it will change base target to blank, but only for duration of download.

Comment: hi again yuriy, i have an error in the document part of the code. is it a variable? if so, how do i declare it? thanks

Comment: No it's intristic, but on the client/browser side, not in server-side code. So if you have a button that starts download, e.g. `<asp:Button id="btExport" Text="Export" runat="server" />` add the above code to it making it `<asp:Button id="btExport" Text="Export" runat="server" OnClientClick="document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].setAttibute('target','')" />` this will modify base on client prior to submitting page back to the server.

Comment: Hello again Yuriy, this does not fix my issue. I think this is because of the post back. Is there any way on how can turn off the base then download it and have it turned on again?

Comment: @GianIsTheName that is what solution above is attempting to do - temporary set target of base to empty string only for the duration of download, for the next, "normal" postback it should be restored. Do you have an ASP button that triggers download? If so, have u tried adding `OnClientClick="document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].setAttibute('target','')‌​"` to it? You mentioned this didn't work - you didn't get a download prompt?

Comment: Hello again Yuriy, yes I did not get any download prompt. It just refreshes the page.

Comment: Ok so the only viable solution that I see if u must use a modal dialog (you absolutely must use modal?) is to open a separate non-modal window from it (with something like `window.open()`) initiate and complete download in that new window and immediatly close the window afterwards.